# How to have an Ember route both with and without query params

Tags: ember.js, routes, query-string

Currently, I have a route that looks like "abc.com/name?age=4". How do I configure my route, so that "abc.com/name" without the query param, "age=4", is still a valid page?

All my route file has right now is:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('name', params);
}
```

Comment: `age=4` is default value due to that you don't want to display it in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [official guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/query-params/) and scroll to the title "Default values and deserialization". What @kumkanillam suggests is to define a default value for the query parameter as in this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1c4327b6fbb29bb39c34d215259ee5b7?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C&route=%2Fmy-route%3Fage%3D5). Take a look at the `my-route` controller. `age` is assigned a default value of 4. If you navigate to `my-rote` with the link `/my-route?age=4` it will convert it to just `/my-route` as you wish.